# List index not updating correctly

Tags: python, list

Printing the list index gives 0 throughout iteration.

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        indices = []
        print len(nums)
        for i in nums:
            sum = 0
            i_ind = nums.index(i)
            print ("i_ind = %d"%(i_ind))
            for j in nums:
                j_ind = nums.index(j)
                print ("j_ind = %d"%(j_ind))
                if i_ind != j_ind:
                    sum = i+j
                    if sum == target:
                        indices.append(i_ind)
                        indices.append(j_ind)
                        return indices
    return 0

# test case
list1  = [3,3]
target = 6
test1  = Solution()
print(test1.twoSum(list1,target))
```

This gives:

```
2
i_ind = 0
j_ind = 0
j_ind = 0
i_ind = 0
j_ind = 0
j_ind = 0
```

But I expect:

```
2
i_ind = 0
j_ind = 0
j_ind = 1
```

As the function should terminate after finding the sum of the first two elements is 6.

Comment: Is this a task from ```hackerrank``` or similar site? You could explain what this code is supposed to do (like find indexes to values that sum up to target)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , this is a debugging problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index() function returns the index of the first occurrence of an element in a list. This is causing the unexpected output in your program. 
For example,

```
arr = [1, 1, 1]
print (arr.index(1))
```

The program always outputs 0, since that's where 1 first occurs.

You can try using the enumerate() method which actually iterates both element wise and index wise.

```
for ind, elem in enumerate(arr):
   # here ind is the index of elem in arr.
   # elem in the element you are currently at while iterating through arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` if you would like to access both index and element.
Coming to your question,

```
k = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
k.index(1)#always returns index of first occurrence. (0)
k.index(2)#always returns index of first occurrence. (2)
```